# CSS Font Rendering Inconsistently

Tags: css, webfonts

[image: Font rendering is inconsistent on page]

On my website I have two `<p>` tags with the same styles associated to them, but they're rendering the imported font inconsistently.

I can see from the computed styles tab in the developer tools of **Chrome** that **the one on the left** has rendered **303 glyphs for Josefin Sans** and **1 glyph for Arial**.

The **text on the right** has rendered **294 glyphs for Josefin Sans** and **58 glyhps for Arial**.

That's the only difference I can see between the two. Why would two bodies of text render differently when they use the same styles?

Comment: It's probably has to do with your whole website's load time. I had a similar problem, but I fixed it by using better fonts.

Comment: Please provide a link to the online version, or a fiddle

Comment: Brian, if two elements render differently, they **do not use the same styles**. Somewhere in your project there is some CSS that only applies to one of them and not to the other. If your provide a [mcve] of your problem it's very easy to figure out what's causing the difference.

Comment: Are these two paragraphs on the same page? (rendered at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

You might already be doing it, but you should consider including the font as a Google font. Generally its a more stable way to implement webfonts :)

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Josefin+Sans

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Josefin+Sans